# ABP support for external user management SSO

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, abp

I would like to use my custom SSO solution for user management. It is based on Identity Server. What I would like is a simple flow:

1. User clicks Login button in ABP-based project and is redirected to SSO page
2. User authenticates in SSO
3. User is redirected back to ABP-based project. ABP-based project gets user information only from SSO.

Does ABP allow to use external SSO? Or maybe it requires some additional functionality from SSO? I am asking because ABP requires Redis cache when using separated Identity Server(https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/3487). The cache is used to share some state between Identity Server and api, but I cannot find solid information about it

Comment: The lack of response to such a basic question gives the impression that ABP cannot provide good support. This does not encourage the use of this project…